# how to show two splash screen one by one with skip button in android

Tags: android

i am new to android. i want to show two splash screen one by one with skip button at bottom. when user press the skip button, it will redirect to home activity..can anyone tell me how to do this...? i will really appreciate..i know how to display single splash screen :

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        /*
         * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
         * want to show case your app logo / company
         */

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // This method will be executed once the timer is over
            // Start your app main activity
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, PushNotificationMainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

            // close this activity
            finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
}
```

but i want two splash screen..how can i do..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simplest solution for your question.

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        Runnable runnable;
        private Handler handler;

        public static Intent getIntent(Context context, boolean path) {
            Intent filesIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            filesIntent.putExtra("splash", path);
            return filesIntent;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            final boolean b = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("splash", false);
            if(b){
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);
            } else {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            }

            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            handler = new Handler();

            runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(b){
                        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        startActivity(MainActivity.getIntent(MainActivity.this, true));
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            };

            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3000);
        }

        public void buttonSkip(View view) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
```

if you have any doubt, comment on this... :)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create `Handler`  show second screen and user press skip button then show **MainActivity**

```
final android.os.Handler  handler = new android.os.Handler();


        final Runnable runnable=new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                // go to next screen (second screen in queue)

            }
        };

    handler.postDelayed(runnable,SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
```

**For second screen Do the same as above**

> when user press skip button

```
    btnUsingEkyc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // start your main screen
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

create two screens 1 & 2 place the button skip on screen 1 and on click redirect him to the second screen and place skip button on screen 2 also on click of skip you can redirect him to where ever you want.

you can use this in button on click so it will move to the screen where ever you want.

```
Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, PushNotificationMainActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final int Tick = 1000; // change view after five second ok
    public static final int Complete = 10000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new CountDownTimer(Complete, Tick) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                if (millisUntilFinished < (Complete / 2)) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Layout no 2 Visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Layout no 1 Visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "go to next activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }.start();

    }
}
```

Comment: but how do i put skip button..?

Answer (score 0):

As you know how to call next activity when the timer ends, you can use below logic:

Considering skip button on both screens-

**SplashActivityOne**

In intent, call SplashActivityTwo (after timer ends)

*If skip button clicked* - stop the timer(handler.removeCallbacks) - call HomeActivity

**SplashActivityTwo**

In intent, call HomeActivity (after timer ends)

*If skip button clicked* - stop the timer(handler.removeCallbacks) - call HomeActivity

Answer (score 0):

Add one skip button in your layout file

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.skip);button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, PushNotificationMainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

        // close this activity
        finish();
}});
```